# How can I concatenate items in a 2 dimensional array to a single string?

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

Let's say I have a 2d array like so

```
T = [["w", 'b'],["y",'b','w'],["f","z"]]
```

For a one dimensional array I know I would do something like `T2 = ' '.join(T)` but it doesn't work the same way on a 2d array, I tried to iterate through the array but to no avail.

I want to concatenate the items inside of each separate array inside T. How can I do this?

Comment: "I tried to iterate through the array..."  If you post what you tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Also, what would you expect as a result of concatenating `T`?

Comment: I want the result to be something like T2 = [["w b"],["y b w"]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to concatenate the strings in each individual inner list you can do something like

```
T2 = [' '.join(a) for a in T]
```

or

```
T2 = list(map(' '.join, T))
```

Either of these will spit out a list of strings consisting of the concatenated strings of the inner list.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this was what I needed, I am not great at python and still need to learn a lot more :)

Comment: you're probably going to want to read up of comprehensions (the first line was a list comprehension, there are also dictionary, set, and generator comprehensions). They're really useful